# Where to put a dll file so that it can be used without reference?

Tags: visual-studio, dll

I've created a dll file and now I want to be able to use it without add it to the "References", like the "System" dll, where you can just type "System.(...)"

Where should I put the dll file? Or is it impossible to do?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the file as a reference. Then you can call it by using the full namespace or you can add a using statement. The other way would be to compile your libraries code into you new project so you do not need a DLL.

Comment: Yep, adding the reference is what allows you to "just type "System.(...)""